# Difference between Siddhas meditating on demigods and on Supreme Being?

Tags: yoga, siddhi

In Bhagavad Gita, Lord Krishna said..

> yajante sattvika devan
>   yaksa-raksamsi rajasah
>   pretan bhuta-ganams
>   canye yajante tamasa janah

*Men in the mode of goodness worship the demigods;

those in the mode of passion worship the yakshas and rakshasas;

and those in the mode of ignorance 
worship ghosts and spirits.*

What about Siddhis meditating on Supreme being? What is the difference between those Siddhis who meditate on the demigods and those who meditate on supreme being? Will there be any difference of the powers?

Comment: What do you mean by Siddhis?

Comment: I mean actually the people who have siddhis? I don't know what we call them, so I just put Siddhis there.

Comment: OK, so are you just looking for the difference in powers in between those who worship Vishnu and those who worship other beings?

Comment: yes, it is what I am looking for.

Comment: The siddhis obtained by meditating (whether on demigods or on the Supreme being) are still just siddhis. Siddhis or powers are merely obstacles on the path towards God. These serve to increase ego and attachment to desires. These must be let go. But there is one difference between the two. The one meditating on Demigods, takes these siddhis as 'powers' that has obtained by means of his own self effort, thus ruining himself by abusing them. Whereas the one meditating on the Lord Himself, views these Siddhis as God-given gifts to be used to serve Him, thus redeeming Himself! All d best Sir

Comment: Who is the supreme being?

Comment: @Sai Are siddhis attained only due to certain practices?

Comment: @JavaTechnical siddhis means powers. Powers are like this, as you learn swimming, you also develop better breathing capacity right. As you eat tablet, you get side effects. similarly as you begin concentrating on GOd (or on demigod) you begin to get side effects. These side effects are siddhis. Are they good or bad? They are mostly obstacles because they make you believe that you have 'earned' some kind of powers from God and thus ego begins to rise. Sri Ramakrishnaji in Gospel said that when He began to get various powers, He at once surrendered them to God, He said they were obstacles to GOd

Comment: That means any path to the god (*bhakti yoga, karma yoga, jnana yoga*) can get Siddhis? But some say that Siddhis are attained through *Tantra Sastra* and *Hatha Yoga*. Are they the only ways?

Comment: No they are not only ways. Any path to God does (not necessarily) have the possibility to obtain siddhis. The Jnani views these as natural side effects. The Bhakta views these as 'gifts' to serve Him and sometimes as 'tests' to test His devotion. The karm views this as natural laws and does not interfere with it, nor distracted by that. The general rule is this: Put the focus away from the siddhis and put the focus on God (it's easier to say). Then all will be good.

Answer (score 1):

*Short answer* : NO

*Detailed Answer*

The people with Siddhis are called as 'Siddhas'. Siddhis can be considered a *level* in a person's spiritual development, hence the level is the same whoever you meditate on, just the manifestation may vary a little.

The scriptures talk about 8 Siddhis that can be attained like being heavier than a mountain, lighter than air etc.

People who worship demigods cannot very easily go beyond this level since prayers to demigods only satisfies one's *desire* but to meditate on the Supreme one must go *beyond desire*, hence great Siddhas normally don't pride themselves over their powers and concentrate on the attainment of the Supreme.

Notable examples are Hanuman, Shankaracharya, Vivekananda, Ramakrishna etc.

Comment: Demigods in the sense? Examples?

Comment: By demigods i mean the devas like indra etc.

Comment: Could you tell me who are 'NOT' demigods?

Comment: By demigods i mean people who have attained the 'posts' of devas by doing some yajna,also some family deities can be considered so,also bhutas,pretas and pitrus.The Trimurthis,Sakthi are examples of 'not demigods' since they are large sparks of the supreme,nay, the supreme being itself

Comment: Lord Ganesha and Karthikeya?

Comment: they are not demigods as karthikeya is known to have given the knowledge of 'Aum' to lord shiva himself and Lord Ganesha is said to have sent a famous saint to heaven

Comment: But both are sons of Lord Shiva and it is Lord Shiva from where Knowledge comes. Lord Shiva is before they both.

Answer (score 1):

This is from [Bhagavad-gita 17.4](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/17/4). This *shloka* talks about worship in different *guna* of material nature. But *Ishvara*, the Supreme Being, is said to be above the *gunas* of material nature, as said right in the previous *shloka*, in [7.13](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/7/13).

People who worship the Supreme Being do not get any *siddhi*, if *Ishvara* considers it unnecessary for their service. However, obviously, He *can* grant *anything* to the one worshiping Him.

The important difference is, relationship with the Supreme Lord is completely above the material world. If you depend on some material stuff, then He will give you that, be it *siddhi* (supernatural powers), *kama* (satisfaction of the senses) or *artha* (prosperity), but the goal of relationships with Him is complete detachment from anything material not related to the devotional service. It's not even *moksha*.

Worshipping the *devas* like Indra or Brahma or any other *deva* can benefit you in the area covered by this *deva*, but those blessings will stay within the material world, meaning, they'll end when you inevitably die.

Answer (score 0):

Please read Kena Upanishad (I. 5-9). verse 5 says "That which cannot be expressed by speech, but by which speech is expressed--That alone is Brahman, and not that which people here worship." 'not that which people here worship' refers to the good deities that people worship. They are not the real Brahman. You should not see Brahman in that which is not Brahman. By worshiping deities you can get siddhis, but not moksha.

Also see Patanjali's Yoga Aphorisms (III. 51-55) on the Samyama to obtain moksha. The previous verses in the same chapter refer to the siddhis that can be obtained but do not lead to moksha.

Siddhis means powers. Siddha means a man who has attained success.

Comment: What is the use of those `siddhis'?

Comment: @javatechnical They can make you a god or make you powerful. But they only divert you away from moksha. They only lead to rebirth.

Comment: Do you mean using them leads to re-birth or what?

Comment: It does mean that either you use them or not use them, you'll end up re-birthing here again. You do not need any _siddhi_ to gain moksha.